# Allowing the <font> tag to override CSS?

Tags: css

I have some user generated content I'm trying to render on my site. The rich text box editor I'm using renders font changes using `<font />` tags, which are overridden by CSS on the page.

Does anyone know if there is a way to allow rules defined using the `<font />` tag to show through?

**UPDATE**
Since changing the control I'm using for my rich text editor is not an option and my users have no knowledge of HTML to understand the difference between a `<font>` tag and any other type of tag, I had no choice but to create a hack to fix my problem. Below is the code I used to solve it. It's a jQuery script that changes all `<font />` tag attributes into inline CSS.

```
(function() {
    $('font[size]').each(function() {
        var fontSize = this.size;
        if (fontSize == 1) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 8);
        } else if (fontSize == 2) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 9);
        } else if (fontSize == 3) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 11);
        } else if (fontSize == 4) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 15);
        } else if (fontSize == 5) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 20);
        } else if (fontSize == 6) {
            $(this).css("font-size", 25);
        }
    });
    $('font[face]').each(function() {
        $(this).css('font-family', this.face);
    });
    $('font[color]').each(function() {
        $(this).css('color', this.color);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A year late, but thought I'd share nonetheless.

I was frustrated by this, as well. I was using a freeware RTE JavaScript component that produced `<FONT />` tags. It wasn't convenient to replace it, as it was for a client and it was a callback to fix this CSS override problem.

Unfortunately, none of the other solutions worked in my case, so after thinking I came up with this JavaScript solution:

```
var fontEl=document.getElementsByTagName("font");
for(var i=0;i<fontEl.length;i++) {
    var f = fontEl[i];
    if(f.size)
        f.style.fontSize=(Math.round(parseInt(f.size)*12*0.6)).toString()+'px';
    if(f.face)
        f.style.fontFamily=f.face;
    if(f.color)
        f.style.color=f.color;
}
```

The formula for converting font size is incorrect, but accurate enough to produce believable results.

Comment: I like your solution. It's definitely more efficient than mine. Were you using jQuery when you tried using my solution, or was it just incompatible with what you were trying to do? Also, keep in mind that `parseInt()` can be dangerous if you don't pass in the radix you're converting from: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseInt

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I used the latest jQuery release included from google's API library. I bound it to document.ready, thinking that would be the right way to do it. No luck.

By the way, I noticed a syntax error in my posted code.
Line 3:
"var f=f;" -- should read "var f=fontEl[i];"

Also thanks for the tip on passing the radix. Looks like I need to brush up on some things!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest overriding the CSS with your own styles that implement the !important attribute.

```
div.MyClass p 
{  
font-size: 0.7em !important; 
}
```

The font tag, technically should override most styles as long as it's the closest element to the raw text.

If it's failing it's likely due to the CSS using the !important attribute to override it.

Comment: I know the tag doesn't follow standards, but the rich text box editor I'm using generates text using the <font> tag anyway so I have no choice but to allow it. I could override styles with inline CSS, but that won't fix the <font> tag.

Comment: You're going to need to make sure the font tag is the closest element to the text, and that there are no !important styles in your CSS as they will override this.

Comment: For providing irrelevant information. The question was not about `<font style="font-size=150%">` tag - which generally works unless poverriden by importance flag, and which the author ALREADY does by his JS fix. But the question was about `<font size="+2">` which does not work despite being most local most narrow and all that

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to a `style` tag on the element. Anything in that would take precedence over style sheet defined rules.

Comment: Not entirely true, you can still override inline elements with the !important attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? Get a new rich text editor! [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) are both okay choices. Either that or educate your users to understand that the styles they set in the editor won't necessarily appear that way when published. Once thing I've done with FCKeditor in the past is limit its toolbar to the basics, like lists, links, headings etc., no styling options whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

<font> is just an element like any other; it can be styled using CSS.  You can write CSS to allow the font tag's styles to push down as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { color: black}
    a { color: red; font-family: Sans; font-size: 14px;}
    font * { color: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is outside <a href="#">inside</a> outside. <font color="green" face="Times New Roman" size="20">Outside <a href="#">inside</a> outside</font>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only problem with that is any tags inside the <font> tag get their styles overridden, even if they have their own styles, such as the link tag within the font tag.